# Writing AudioRecord buffers from while loop into array

Tags: java, arrays, audiorecord

I don't know how to write short arrays generated inside of while loop into a bigger array outside of while loop. I want to make them concatenated like so [first iteration, second iteration, third iteration...etc].

i tired making a big array and putting values in by remembering the last position but the application crashes

```
byte audioData[] = new byte[1024];
while (isRecording) {
    recorder.read(audioData, 0, 1024);

    // Converting from byte array to short array 
    short[] audioDataF = byteToShort(audioData);

    for (int i = 0; i < audioDataF.length; i++) {
        realdata[positionsaver * audioDataF.length +i]= audioDataF[i];
    }
    positionsaver++;          
}

I would like to have an array of PCM data but my app crashes :<
```

Comment: If your app crashes you probably get some exception or error with a message and a stacktrace. If so please post that in a nice format.

Comment: `realdata[positionsaver * audioDataF.length +i]` - since `audioDataF` is created inside the loop could the length differ? If so, your calculation will be very fragile because once you get a shorter array you'll overwrite data whereas for a longer array you'll skip elements. - Why do you want to have such a huge combined array in the first place?

Comment: Another note: `// Converting from byte array to float array and dividing floats by 32768 to get values between 0 and 1` and `short[] ...` doesn't match. `short` is an integer type, i.e. it can't hold values _between_ 0 and 1 - it would be only 0 or 1.

Comment: And one more from me: audioDataF.length is always 1024. To get the actual amount of data read from the AudioRecord instance, save the return value of recorder.read()

Comment: I want to create an array of values in order to make Digital signal processing on it. My friend wrote a code which takes an array as an input and i need to provide him with a double array to work with. i don't know how to get an error message form the phone. I am really new to this and just tried to make an array of recording samples.

Comment: realdata array will have to contain 10 seconds of recording with sampling rate of 8kHz, i wanted it to be 1 kHz but when i change the sampling rate the app crashes